# MLE Where Observations are Frequency Counts

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Consider independent trials, such that for each trial
>
> a type 1 outcome will occur with probability $p_1= \frac{1}{2} +
>  \frac{\theta}{4}$
>
> a type 2 outcome will occur with probability $p_2=
>  \frac{1}{2}−\frac{\theta}{2}$
>
> a type 3 outcome will occur with probability $p_3= \frac{\theta}{4}$
>
> where $\theta\in(0,1)$
>
> (a) Letting $N_i$ be the number of type $i$ outcomes that occur in $n$
>   trails give an unbiased frequency substitution estimator of $\theta$
>   based on just $N_1$.
>
> (b) Give the variance of the unbiased estimator requested in part (a)
>
> (c) Given that the observed counts for the three possible outcomes
>   that occur in $20$ trials are $n_1= 11$, $n_2= 5$, and $n_3= 4$, give
>   the mle of $\theta$.

**My Attempt:**

(a) We have

$$p_1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\theta}{4} \Rightarrow \hat{\theta}=4p_1-2=4\left(\frac{N_1}{n}\right)-2$$

(b) We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Var}(\hat{\theta})
&=\mathsf{Var}(4\hat{p_1}-2)\\\\
&=\mathsf{Var}\left(4\left(\frac{N_1}{n}\right)-2\right)\\\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{n}\right)^2 \mathsf{Var}(N_1) \\\\
&=\left(\frac{16}{n^2}\right) np_1(1-p_1)\\\\
&=\frac{16}{n}\left(\frac{\theta+2}{4}\right)\left(\frac{2-\theta}{4}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{4-\theta^2}{n}
\end{align*}$$

(c) We have

$$\begin{align*}
L(\vec{\theta}\mid\vec{N})
&=\frac{(N_1+N_2+N_3)!}{N_1!N_2!N_3!}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\theta}{4}\right)^{N_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{N_2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)^{N_3}\\\\
&=c\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\theta}{4}\right)^{N_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{N_2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)^{N_3}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Upon taking the natural log of both sides, we get

$$\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{N})=\text{log}c+N_1 \text{log }\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\theta}{4}\right)+N_2\text{log}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+N_3\text{log}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)$$

Hence

$$0=\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{N})=\frac{N_1}{\theta+2}-\frac{N_2}{1-\theta}+\frac{N_3}{\theta}$$

Solving for $\theta$ is nontrivial so I used software to obtain

$$\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=\frac{-N_1+2N_2+N_3\pm \sqrt{9N_3^2+12N_2N_3+6N_3N_1+4N_2^2-4N_2N_1+N_1^2}}{-2n}$$

From here, I get that $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=\{0.562, -0.712\}$ but since we are given that $\theta\in(0,1)$ it must be that $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=0.562$. Is it okay to say this or would the mle not exist since it is not unique?

Are these valid solutions?

Comment: Capital $N$ and small $n$ are switched in question a and c.

Comment: part of them were fixed. use 0.562 as a solution. Then 11/2.562 + 5/0.438 + 4/0.562 > 20 $\ne$ 0. My calculation is wrong?. You forget the log after N_2 and N_3 in log likelihood.

Comment: Whoops, I think I did the calculations with the logs present though.

Comment: There's a minus sign before $\frac{5}{0.438}$

Comment: the denominator 1-0.562 = -0.438. combine with - before fraction, get +.

Comment: $1-0.562\neq -0.438$

Comment: Sorry. Then you can say that $\hat \theta_{MLE}=0.562.$ not unique is common, Generally you can find the other solutions beyond your range.